# How to auto compensate CSS underline for varying scripts? Currently it is not always under the text and is inconsistent

Tags: html, css

So here's an example of some underlined English text.

[image: English Text]

Granted the decender of the "p" does overlap the line, but otherwise it's quite clearly "under" the text.

On the other hand, let's look at Chinese:

[image]

It's certainly not above the text, but it's also not strictly below it. It's sort of "among the bottom" of the text. Now before anyone say "those are just decenders like the 'p' in English". I'm not so sure about that. The bottom of the English text(without decenders) aligns with the bottom of the period. The underline is completely beneath the period(top of underline aligns with bottom of period).

underline ->    ▃ ▀  <- period

But in the Chinese text the underline is aligned with the bottom of the period, rather underneath it(bottom of underline aligned with bottom of period.).

underline ->    ▀ ▀  <- period

I went through about 8 other non-latin scripts, and about half were solidly underlines, while the other half were "underish"-lines.

I'm aware I can offset the text underline, but I don't know which scripts need what amount of offset, and I'm dealing with over 100 languages. Is there anyway to say to CSS, I'd love for my underlines to be underlines, and not aspiring strike throughs?

Korean is best of the worst. Ever so slighly off, and if it was the worst of it, I could live with it.
[image]

Mongolian isn't too bad, but definitely seems to have a pretty lax definition of "descender".
[image]

Amharic is about as bad as Chinese, maybe worse.
[image]
Here's Chinese again with colors swapped out to be even more obvious.
[image]

EDIT: It appears this only happens on Chrome/Brave.

Brave:

[image]

Firefox:

[image]

Used fonts:

One:

[image]

Two:

[image]

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration-skip-ink

Comment: would you share codepen example link?

Comment: It is not a CSS issue but rather a question of the font and where the Font-Designer added the baseline to the font.

Comment: @tacoshy It seems that it is a CSS issue, but only on chromium. I just tested on firefox, and the issue does not happen on Firefox, even though Firefox and Chrome are stating they are both using the exact same font. Images added above.

Comment: @Paulie_D Did you even bother to read my question? Or did you just see "underline" and link the first MDN page about underlines?

Comment: @sawacrow Sure, here you go [codepen](https://codepen.io/bobbybrownsson/pen/MWxbpzE). But i've since discovered this seems to be a chromium issue. Firefox correctly puts the line under the text, but chromium doesn't.

Comment: It seems difficult to work with Far Eastern alphabets.
I think: text-underline-offset: 10px; you can give different offsets for each font-family with . this seems like the simplest solution.

Comment: @sawacrow Hardly seems easy. How am I supposed to detect if a given browser does or does not correctly place the underline? And if they don't, how am I supposed to know by how much. Just adding 10px blindly to every piece of text will not solve my problem of inconsistent text underlines, it'll just make it look weirder now that the underline is 10 pixels too low most of the time.

Comment: @PeterR 
There is no such technology. The system cannot detect this. My suggestion is to just write css for the most commonly used browsers. Safari and Chrome.
Also, the css support feature does not work properly. Since it is a specific issue, it requires a specific solution. You can give all:unset to each font family class and rewrite it. So it probably looks the same in every browser. But if not, you may need to write specifically for each browser and font family.